# In DBF, "Ñ" character is showed as "¥"

Tags: visual-foxpro, dbf

I open a DBF file in Visual FoxPro and it shows "Ñ" character as "¥". I haven't created that DBF, I just open it and read it.

[image]

My question is: Is there any way to show those "¥" characters correctly in FoxPro? Or does it mean that this DBF file was created wrongly?

Comment: That's character code 165, a Ñ in code page 437.  Which is the legacy IBM PC (aka OEM) character set, likely to be used by very old programs.  Same code in code page 1252 is ¥

Comment: Do home()+"tools\CpZero\CpZero" with "yourTable.dbf", 437

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to know which encoding was used when the file was saved, depending on the version number of the file. Also the MSDN has a dedicated page about this topic. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5b10d8b6(v=vs.80).aspx

In specific the first paragraph might be for your interest:

> When you create .dbf files, Visual FoxPro automatically gives them
>   code page marks so that you can tell which code pages they use.
>   However, if you use .dbf files from previous versions of FoxPro, they
>   might not have code page marks. You can determine whether a .dbf file
>   has a code page mark by using the CPDBF( ) function after opening the
>   file or by having Visual FoxPro check when you open the file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the proper code page of your DBF file.

To know it, open the file with [DBF Commander Pro](http://dbf-software.com/), click '*Tools -> Set Codepage*', then try to [set the proper encoding](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-tools.html#SetCP) by choosing various encodings from the list (leave '*Preview*' check box turned on):
[image: DBF encoding]

The program has 30-day fully functional trial period, so you can do your task at no charge.

Comment: You can also set the codepage for a DBF with the program CPZero.PRG that comes with VFP. You'll find it in the Tools\CPZero folder. Pass the filename and the codepage you want.